Optimal settings for accurate and fast printing?
So, I'm new to the 3D printing scene, I'm a 3D artist by trade. I'm freelancing for a guy who's got a Creality Ender 3 with a nozzle size of 0.8 mm. I need to 3D print a lampshade of 2 mm thick all around, except for the base which is 3 mm. The object is 178 mm (7 in) tall and 165 mm (6.5 in) wide. What print settings do I need to set to finish this print within 7~9 hours while having an acceptable loss in accuracy or quality?
I am using Ultimaker Cura to make the .gcode file as that is what was recommended to me, however, I'm open to other software if they are better.
Any other tips or tricks are also appreciated.



Seeing the size of this thing, 7-9 hours without compromising quality, on Ender 3, is a tall ask.

@SF. maybe i should update the question.... more like with an acceptable loss in quality

Without having access to the model, I'd seriously wonder how we could check? Why 2 mm walls and 3 mm base? Must the base be solid? I'd start with setting the extrusion width for the 0.8 mm nozzle to 1 mm and the layer height to 0.5 mm. Be sure to find the maximum allowable flow for the hotend with this setting, you may need to lower the standard print speeds.

@0scar i made the model myself to i can tweak the shape as and how needed... this is a hanging lamp shade to be made, 2mm wall thickness allows most of the light to pass through and base is 3mm so the bulb and the weight of the lamp doesn't break it

In order for us to make sure that the printing time stays within the limits set by the requirements, we should have access to the STL model to test the prognosed time to print this object according to the used slicer.
Furthermore, we'd need information on the printer, specifically the print speed with using the hotend on the printer from the requirements.
As we do not have such information, we could only direct you to some hints to slice the model yourself. First, as the wall requirement is 2.0 mm, the most sensible way to minimize time is to cit on the amount of walls that need to be printed. You could set the extrusion width to 1.0 mm so that the wall is exactly 2 perimeters wide. Know that an extrusion width of 1.0 mm may be too much for your hotend to deliver, you need to find that out first. Based on this analysis, you could choose the layer height to fit the maximum flow capacity of the hotend, or the maximum of about 75 % of the extrusion width; this implies a layer height with a maximum of 0.7 mm.
Second, does the base of the lamp need to be a solid 3.0 mm? You could have Different infill in the same part to increase the rigidity or strength where it is needed.
Last, check that the retraction settings are correct (enough distance/length set to not retract), you may want to disable retraction, this uses much time.
With these tips you should be able to re-slice the model and assess the printing time.
